# How to show that if squares are equal, then the operands are equal as well?

Tags: coq

I had a problem finishing the proof of this Lemma :

```
Lemma l1 : forall m n  : nat, m * m = n * n -> m = n.
```

any hint would be very helpful.

I started the proof like this:

```
Require Import Arith Omega Nat.
Lemma l1 : forall m n  : nat, m * m = n * n -> m = n.
Proof.
intros.
destruct (Nat.eq_dec m n ).
trivial.
induction n.
induction m.
auto.
simpl in H;congruence.
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is a question about Coq? Have you really tried to prove this lemma with pen and paper? If you have, please share with us the main steps of your proof and we can help you formalize it. Remember: it's not because Coq tells you that the first steps are OK that you are necessarily heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A hint**: take the square root of the both sides of your hypothesis, then it leads immediately to the conclusion. For the square root function use `Nat.sqrt` from the `Arith` module.

**First solution**:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma l1 : forall m n : nat, m * m = n * n -> m = n.
Proof.
  intros m n H. apply (f_equal Nat.sqrt) in H.
  now repeat rewrite Nat.sqrt_square in H.
Qed.
```

**Second solution:**

The lemma can also be proved using the `nia` tactic, an incomplete proof procedure for integer non-linear arithmetic:

```
Require Import Psatz.

Lemma l1 m n : m * m = n * n -> m = n.
Proof. nia. Qed.
```

**Third solution:**

Let's use a couple times the standard `Nat.square_le_simpl_nonneg` lemma:

```
forall n m : nat, 0 <= m -> n * n <= m * m -> n <= m
```

Here we go:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma l1 (m n : nat) :
  m * m = n * n -> m = n.
Proof with (auto with arith).
  intros H.
  pose proof (Nat.eq_le_incl _ _ H) as Hle.
  pose proof (Nat.eq_le_incl _ _ (eq_sym H)) as Hge.
  apply Nat.square_le_simpl_nonneg in Hle...
  apply Nat.square_le_simpl_nonneg in Hge...
Qed.
```

**Fourth solution:**

Here is a classical proof, based on the following equality

```
m * m - n * n = (m + n) * (m - n)
```

Firstly, we'll need a helper lemma, proving the above equality (Surprisingly, it seems that the standard library is lacking this lemma):

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

(* can be proved using `nia` tactic *)
Lemma sqr_diff (m n : nat) :
    m * m - n * n = (m + n) * (m - n).
Proof with (auto with arith).
  destruct (Nat.lt_trichotomy m n) as [H | [H | H]].
  - pose proof H as H'.    (* copy hypothesis *)
    apply Nat.square_lt_mono_nonneg in H...
    repeat match goal with
      h : _ < _ |- _ => apply Nat.lt_le_incl, Nat.sub_0_le in h
    end.
    rewrite H, H'...
  - now rewrite H, !Nat.sub_diag.
  - rewrite Nat.mul_add_distr_r, !Nat.mul_sub_distr_l.
    rewrite Nat.add_sub_assoc...
    replace (n * m) with (m * n) by apply Nat.mul_comm.
    rewrite Nat.sub_add...
Qed.
```

And now we can prove the main lemma:

```
Lemma l1 (m n : nat) :
    m * m = n * n -> m = n.
Proof.
  intros H.
  pose proof (Nat.eq_le_incl _ _ H) as Hle;
  pose proof (Nat.eq_le_incl _ _ (eq_sym H)) as Hge; clear H.
  rewrite <- Nat.sub_0_le in *.
  rewrite sqr_diff in *.
  destruct (mult_is_O _ _ Hle) as [H | H].
  now destruct (plus_is_O _ _ H); subst.
  destruct (mult_is_O _ _ Hge) as [H' | H'].
  now destruct (plus_is_O _ _ H'); subst.
  rewrite Nat.sub_0_le in *.
  apply Nat.le_antisymm; assumption.
Qed.
```